# weird array output... How to distribute array into words and be able to print them out?

Tags: ruby, arrays, serialization, ruby-on-rails-3.1, yaml

I have an array that looks like

```
["", "Fitness", "Stationary", "Looks", "Access", "Food", 
"---\n- Stationary\n- Access\n- ''\n"] ["", "Fitness", 
"Stationary", "Looks", "Access", "Food", "---\n- Stationary\n- Access\n- ''\n"]
```

I use the following code to go through them...

```
<h3>Categories</h3>
<% for product in Product.select(:category)%>
    <% a = [""].concat(Product.select(:category).map(&:category).uniq) %>
<% end %>
<% a.each do |c| %>
    <p class="text-error"><%= link_to(c.delete("-"), ) %></p>
<% end %>
```

I get something like this...

```
Fitness
Stationary
Looks
Access
Food
Stationary Access ''
```

The full code is available at:
    https://github.com/abhishekdagarit/sample-app.git

How to solve this? 
If there is dirty data in the database, How can I clean that?

What is the problem here? And How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have YAML in your array:

```
jruby-1.7.0.preview2 :001 > require 'yaml'
 => true 
jruby-1.7.0.preview2 :002 > a = ["", "Fitness", "Stationary", "Looks", "Access", "Food", "---\n- Stationary\n- Access\n- ''\n"]
 => ["", "Fitness", "Stationary", "Looks", "Access", "Food", "---\n- Stationary\n- Access\n- ''\n"] 
jruby-1.7.0.preview2 :003 > YAML.load(a.last)
 => ["Stationary", "Access", ""]
```

which means you have probably have junk in your `category` column of the `products` table.  How it got there, not sure; maybe some strange stuff happened when seeding data from a yml file?

The best way to avoid this kind of situations is to make a reference table named for example `categories` and reference this table with a `category_id` foreign key in the `products` table.  That way, when creating a product, you can display a dropdown with only the valid categories in it – and prevent invalid categories from being added to the db.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will start with it to see if it helps.